# Regex to Validate URL and URL with file extension

Tags: c#, regex, url

I have a scenario for a hyperlink control, where user can provide either URL(**http://:85/UI/FormRenderer**) or URL with some file path (**http://:85/UI/FormRenderer/Content/images/Close.png**) . I need to validate for proper URL when URL is given, and need to validate for proper URL with file path when file path is provided, Currently I am struck with distinguishing between URL and URL with file path. Below is what I tried:

```
private static bool ValidateURL(string url)
    {
        bool stat = false;
        var matURL = Regex.Match(url, @"^(https?|ftp|file)://.+$");

        Match matFileType=null;
        if(matURL.Success)
            matFileType = Regex.Match(url, @"^.*\.(jpg|JPG|gif|GIF|doc|DOC|pdf|PDF)$");

        if (matFileType != null)
            stat = matFileType.Success;
        else
            stat = false;            
        return stat;
    }
```

Comment: Any url can point to a file, even if it has no extension. What is your question? "How to find out if a url ends with an extension?" Also can you explain why you are stuck? What seems to be the problem?

Comment: @CodeCaster: User can give either url or url with file extension, I need to validate for a proper url if a url is given. I need to validate for proper url with file extension when a file extension is given. Two different validations I have to do based on the URL or URL with file extension. Hope you understood my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need a regex? In C#, you could use the Uri class for validating the urls in general. For example, the following two will work:

```
    new Uri("http://blahblah");
    new Uri("https://localhost");
```

These three will throw exceptions:

```
    new Uri("https://:80");
    new Uri("https:///example.com");
    new Uri("://example.com");
```

Uri class will verify that the Uri is a valid Uri. Whether a file exists or not at a given Uri is something that you will have to write code for. It wouldn't be covered by regex either. However if your question is to check whether the Uri is valid as per the specification when provided for a file, then the Uri class will handle that too.

For validating correct file extensions, you can check whether the URL ends with certain strings, such as ".png", ".jpg" using String.EndsWith.

Comment: Or even [`Uri.IsWellFormedUriString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx) if you don't want to throw exceptions.